# How do I... truncate string in an array

Tags: ruby, truncate

In a ruby on rails app, I build an array of Project Names and project id values, but want to truncate the length of the names.  Current code is:

```
names  = active_projects.collect {|proj| [proj.name, proj.id]}
```

I have tried to add a truncate function to the block, but am getting undefined method for class error.

Thanks in advance - I just cannot wrap my head around this yet.

Comment: Sounds like you're on the right track. It might be that you just need the `include` from my answer to make the `truncate` method available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I understood the question properly:

```
max_length = 10 # this is the length after which we will truncate
names = active_projects.map { |project|
  name = project.name.to_s[0..max_length] # I am calling #to_s because the question didn't specify if project.name is a String or not
  name << "…" if project.name.to_s.length > max_length # add an ellipsis if we truncated the name
  id = project.id
  [name, id]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Following

```
name=[]
active_projects.collect {|proj| name << [proj.name, proj.id]}
```

EDITED this should be

```
names= active_projects.collect {|proj|  [proj.name.to_s[0..10], proj.id]}
```

Comment: This looks like it will concatenate the strings, not truncate them.

Comment: in fact, it does exactly the same thing as the OP, only worse and semantically wrong.

Comment: it will produce o/p like name= [ ['salil', 1], ['ander', '2'] ].
no check though.

Answer (score 0):

In a Rails application you can use the [truncate](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#M001743) method for this.

If your code isn't in a view then you will need to include the TextHelper module in order to make the method available:

```
include ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper
```

you can then do:

```
names = active_projects.collect { |proj| [truncate(proj.name), proj.id] }
```

The default behaviour is to truncate to 30 characters and replace the removed characters with '...' but this can be overridden as follows:

```
names = active_projects.collect {
  # truncate to 10 characters and don't use '...' suffix
  |proj| [truncate(proj.name, :length => 10, :omission => ''), proj.id]
}
```

Comment: The function was in the model, not in a view.  I added the line you suggested to the project.rb file, but still get the same error as originally reported.  The simpler method of treating the project name (which is a string) as an array and pulling just the first n characters works for now.  Thanks.